# How to do CRUD operation update in angular js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

Hii i am new to angular js ,right now i am working on the crud operation in angular js , i dont know how to do update the data in angularjs which is consuming rest api calls. could you pls help me out ?

my view :

```
      <div ng-repeat="phone in phones">
      <p>{{ phone.sequenceNumber}}. {{ phone.phoneNumber }} ({{ phone.phoneType }}<span ng-if="phone.isPrimary"> primary</span>)</p>
      <button ng-click="updatePhone()"  ng-model="phone.phoneNumber" class="btn btn-small btn-primary">update</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

my controller :

```
 "use strict"

ContactApp.controller("StudentController", [
  '$scope',
  '$http',

  '$state',
  '$sce',
  'UiString',
  'Settings',
  'EmergencyContact',
  'MissingPersonContact',
  'Address',
  'Phone',

  function($scope, $http,$state, $sce, UiString, Settings, EmergencyContact, MissingPersonContact, Address, Phone
  ) {

    EmergencyContact.getContacts($scope.uid).then(function(contacts) {
      $scope.emergencyContacts = contacts;
    });

    MissingPersonContact.getContacts($scope.uid).then(function(contacts) {
      $scope.missingPersonContacts = contacts;
    });

    Address.getLocalAddress($scope.uid).then(function(address) {
      $scope.localAddress = address;
    });

    Phone.getPhones($scope.uid).then(function(phone1) {
      $scope.phones = phone1;
    });



    $scope.newPhoneNumber = '';

    $scope.AddPhone = function() {
      console.log("scope.newPhoneNumber",$scope.newPhoneNumber);

      var newPhone = Phone.addPhone($scope.newPhoneNumber);

      Phone.savePhone($scope.uid, newPhone).then(
        function(response) {
          $scope.phones.push(newPhone);
          return console.log("question", response);
        },
        function(err) {
          return console.log("There was an error "
          + err);
        });

      };

      $scope.updatePhone = function() {


        Phone.savePhone1($scope.uid, newPhone).then(
          function(response) {
            $scope.phones.push(newPhone);
            return console.log("question", response);
          },
          function(err) {
            return console.log("There was an error "
            + err);
          });

        };



      }]);
```

my service :

```
'use strict';

angular.module('ContactApp')
.service('Phone', ['$q', '$http', 'Settings', function($q, $http, Settings) {

  this.getPhones = function(id) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();

    if (id) {
      $http.get(Settings.getSetting('wsRootUrl') +
      '/person/phone/v1/' + id + '?token=' + Settings.getToken()).
      success(function(response) {
        deferred.resolve(response.data);
      }).error(function(data, status) {
        deferred.reject(status);
      });
    } else {
      deferred.resolve({});
    }

    return deferred.promise;
  };

  this.addPhone = function(phoneNumber) {
    var model =
    {
      "pidm": null,
      "phoneType": "CELL",
      "activityDate": null,
      "isPrimary": null,
      "phoneNumber": phoneNumber,
      "sequenceNumber": null,
      "status": null
    };

    return model;
  }

  this.savePhone = function(userId, phone) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    console.log(phone);
    $http.post( Settings.getSetting('wsRootUrl') +
    '/person/phone/v1/' + userId + '?token=' + Settings.getToken()
    , [ phone ]).
    success(function(response) {
      deferred.resolve(response.data);
    }).error(function(data, status) {
      deferred.reject(status);
    });

    return deferred.promise;
  };

  this.updatePhone = function(phoneNumber1) {
    var model =
    {
      "pidm": 123456,
      "phoneType": "CELL",
      "activityDate": null,
      "isPrimary": null,
      "phoneNumber": phoneNumber1,
      "sequenceNumber": null,
      "status": null
    };

    return model;
  }
  this.savePhone1 = function(userId, phone1) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    console.log(phone1);
    $http.put( Settings.getSetting('wsRootUrl') +
    '/person/phone/v1/' + userId + '?token=' + Settings.getToken()
    , [ phone1 ]).
    success(function(response) {
      deferred.resolve(response.data);
    }).error(function(data, status) {
      deferred.reject(status);
    });

    return deferred.promise;
  };

}]);
```

Comment: Make sure getPhone in API call is returning an array else push method will cause an error. Also check developer console and add to description of question it will be more clear than reading whole code.

Comment: find my answer, tell to me if it help to you.

Comment: my console error is showing the ponNumber undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

~~~EDIT~~~~

Okay from what I gather this is what you want:

In HTML inside of ng-repeat:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="phone.phoneNumber" />
```

// at this point when the user types their new phone number in the "phone" object has already been updated (via two-way data binding).
Then if you want to save to database you can send to your service via the controller method $scope.updatePhone with the button.

```
<button ng-click="updatePhone(phone)">Update</button>
```

Then in the controller:

```
$scope.updatePhone = function (phone) {
    console.log("this is the updated phone: ",phone);
    console.log("this is the updated phones array: ",$scope.phones);
    // you should see that the phone number has been updated in scope.

    Phone.updatePhone(phone); 

    // this service call should be a post to the server, not a return object as the object has already been updated.

}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: i want the functionality that the user has able to edit the phonenumber field in the view and able to update the field using that update button . what ihave to change in the service? and how to make the field editable onclicking in the html @ justin herter

Comment: hii justin , for you suggestion the phoneNumber object is going to controller but when in service it shows undefined , could you please suggest hwat i have to change in service.js file

Comment: Hii justin thanks for taking your  time for editing your answer, but my confusion is what i have to wirte in the service.js file ?

Comment: @vyshnavi That is determined by what you are trying to do with the data. What are you trying to do with the data when it gets to the service? Save to Database?

Comment: yes justin herter i would like to save the data to database when its gets to the service @justin herter

Comment: @vyshnavi Why not just call Phone.savePhone instead of update in the controller or create another ajax call to server in the service in place of the current update functionality...?

Answer (score 0):

You can find example here of CRUD operation in AngularJS with Web API to perform Create, Read, Update and Delete functionality. I hope it will be help to you.

[CRUD Operation in AngularJS with Web API](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/65794e/web-api-with-angular-js/)